# My $scope variable not updated

Tags: angularjs

I have the collection of objects which I get from service:

```
$scope.rooms = TestData.list().rooms;

// {"room1":{"name":"Bathroom"},"room2":{"name":"WCC"},"room3":{"name":"Kitchen"}};
```

I need to find room by `$routeParams.id`

```
$scope.room = $scope.rooms[$routeParams.id];

// For example $routeParams.id = 'room1'
```

If I inspect it in a view:

```
{{rooms}}

{{room}}
```

I see how rooms dynamically updated, but room is always `undefined`. But if I call in view something like this:

```
{{room = rooms[roomUid]}}

// $scope.roomUid = $routeParams.id
```

It found room as expected. Why I can not find room in my controller?

**UPDATED:**

I found my problem, my `$scope.rooms` collection is empty when I try to find room by id. With `$timeout` `$scope.room` work like expected, but how start finding room just after `$scope.rooms` was populated?

```
$timeout(function(){$scope.room = $scope.rooms[$routeParams.id];}, 3000);
```

I solved this by:

```
if($routeParams.id){
  $scope.action = 'Edit';
  $scope.roomID = $routeParams.id;
  $scope.$watch('rooms.' + $scope.roomID, function(){
    $scope.room = $scope.rooms[$routeParams.id];        
  });
};
```

It is good?

Comment: it's hard to identify the problem you are experiencing from the bits of pseudo code you posted here.  Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example illustrating what is happening? maybe a plunker? see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$watch` is not required in this case. One would add `$watch` only if the room is dynamically added and at that time you want to do something.

Just check for `$routeParams.id` and if it's not `undefined` start searching for the `room`.

In case you're fetching `rooms` data from service. Then put logic for getting particular room inside the `then` resolve function. In that way you would be sure that the rooms list is available before you search for a particular room.